# How can I increase the value in the text field with JButton?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a school project and I want to do an online shopping cart with Java. It has a frame, 4 different types of clothing with JLabels, one text field that displays 0 in the starting for each of them and two JButtons that have plus and minus icons for each text fields. I want to increase the number which is in the text field with plus button and decrease it with minus button. Also it needs to count how many clothes I want to buy, for calculating the money.

pa = JButton which has a plus sign and need to increase the number of Pants.
pt = JTextField which shows us the number of pants.

```
pa.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        pt.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(pt.getText() + 1)));
    }
});
```

Output:
Pants: 0    (*Press + button once*)    Pants: 1    (*Press + button once*)    Pants: 11

My expectation:
Pants: 0    (*Press + button once*)    Pants: 1    (*Press + button once*)    Pants: 2

Also, decreasing similarly with - button, but I can't.

Also, I tried this one but it didn't work:

```
int counter = 0;
pa.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        counter++;
        pt.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }
});
```

Error: java: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Comment: Why not just use a **JSpinner**  or **JSpinField** component instead of a JTextField, Buttons, icons, etc, etc?

Comment: Make your variable an "instance" variable, not a "local" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach is not far off. There is just a little error in line `pt.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(pt.getText() + 1)));`: the `+1` should not be inside `Integer.value(...)` but right after it.
Your current code gets the text, appends the character `1` to the text, and parses the modified text as number. But you need to get the text, parse the text as number, and then add `1` to the parsed number.
It might help to do each step in a separate line and assign each intermediate result to a local variable instead of doing everything in one statement.

Still, the idea from the second approach is the better one. Change your `int counter` from a local variable to a field of your class and it will work.

Comment: pa.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                pt.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(pt.getText())+1));
                int num = Integer.parseInt(pt.getText());
            }
        });

It worked like that, but can't use "num" outside of ActionListener, do you have any advice for that?

Comment: @camickr Thanks for advice, I will try it. I am a new member, so I don't know the rules. Unfortunately, I noticed that it seems complex when I post my code in comments after I shared it. Sorry for that.